# Seaborn Confusion Matrix (heatmap) 2 color schemes (correct diagonal vs wrong rest)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, confusion-matrix

## Background

In a confusion matrix, the diagonal represents the cases that the predicted label matches the correct label. So the diagonal is good, while all other cells are bad. To clarify what is good and what is bad in a CM for non-experts, I want to give the diagonal a different color than the rest. I want to achieve this with **Python & Seaborn**.

Basically I'm trying to achieve what this question does in R ([ggplot2 Heatmap 2 Different Color Schemes - Confusion Matrix: Matches in Different Color Scheme than Missclassifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504970/ggplot2-heatmap-2-different-color-schemes-confusion-matrix-matches-in-differe))

## Normal Seaborn Confusion Matrix with heatmap

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

cf_matrix = np.array([[50, 2, 38],
                      [7, 43, 32],
                      [9,  4, 76]])

sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True, cmap='Blues')  # cmap='OrRd'
```

Which results in this image:

[image: Seaborn Confusion Matrix with colormap 'Blues']

## Goal

I would like to color the non-diagonal cells with e.g. `cmap='OrRd'`. So I imagine there would be 2 colorbars, 1 blue for the diagonal and 1 for the other cells. Preferably the values of both colorbars match (so both e.g. 0-70 and not 0-70 and 0-40).
How would I approach this?

The following is not made with code, but with photo editing software:

[image: Desired Confusion Matrix color scheme]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `mask=` in the call to `heatmap()` to choose which cells to show. Using two different masks for the diagonal and the off_diagonal cells, you can get the desired output:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

cf_matrix = np.array([[50, 2, 38],
                      [7, 43, 32],
                      [9,  4, 76]])

vmin = np.min(cf_matrix)
vmax = np.max(cf_matrix)
off_diag_mask = np.eye(*cf_matrix.shape, dtype=bool)

fig = plt.figure()
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True, mask=~off_diag_mask, cmap='Blues', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True, mask=off_diag_mask, cmap='OrRd', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cbar_kws=dict(ticks=[]))
```

[image]

If you want to get fancy, you can create the axes using GridSpec to have a better layout:

import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

```py
fig = plt.figure()
gs0 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(1,2, width_ratios=[20,2], hspace=0.05)
gs00 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1,2, subplot_spec=gs0[1], hspace=0)

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0])
cax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[0])
cax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[1])

sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True, mask=~off_diag_mask, cmap='Blues', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, ax=ax, cbar_ax=cax2)
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True, mask=off_diag_mask, cmap='OrRd', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, ax=ax, cbar_ax=cax1, cbar_kws=dict(ticks=[]))
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible to annotate the color bars to note what means good, bad with (add at the bottom): `cax2.set_title("X | O ", loc='right')`. And some additional axis labels and title: `ax.set(xlabel='Predicted label', ylabel='True label', title="Confusion Matrix")`

Answer (score 1):

You could first plot the heatmap with colormap 'OrRd' and then overlay it with a heatmap with colormap 'Blues', with the upper and lower triangle values replaced with NaN's, see the following example:

```
def diagonal_heatmap(m):

    vmin = np.min(m)
    vmax = np.max(m)    
    
    sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True, cmap='OrRd', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

    diag_nan = np.full_like(m, np.nan, dtype=float)
    np.fill_diagonal(diag_nan, np.diag(m))
    
    sns.heatmap(diag_nan, annot=True, cmap='Blues', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cbar_kws={'ticks':[]}) 




cf_matrix = np.array([[50, 2, 38],
                      [7, 43, 32],
                      [9,  4, 76]])

diagonal_heatmap(cf_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a related question, somebody asked how to show a correlation dataframe where the colorbar range doesn't include the diagonal (which is all 1's).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris').drop(columns=['species'])
corr_df = iris.corr()

plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
ax = sns.heatmap(corr_df, annot=True, cmap='OrRd', mask=np.eye(len(corr_df)))
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), va='center')
ax.patch.set_facecolor('skyblue')
ax.patch.set_edgecolor('white')
ax.patch.set_hatch('xx')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap for a correlation matrix without the diagonal]